# Insert every other row to a Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this Table with one row `Transaction Date` the first row is the `checkIn` and the second one is the `Checkout` if we organized the result by date asc.

I need to pass the second row value to another column named `Checkout`. This table has at least 1000 records

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  I assume you mean "earlier" and "later" (based on transaction date) rather than "first" and "second".

Comment: How do you identify a pair of records? Records having the same Student ID, Course ID, Device ID and Reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the query below

```
With CteCheckOut as(
Select
ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition by studentID Order by studentID,transactionDate) as Rownumber,
*
From student
)
Select studentID, transactionDate as CheckOutDate
From CteCheckOut
Where Rownumber%2 = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by studentid order by transactiondate) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 2;
```

This assumes that only `studentid` is used to identify the "first" and "second" rows.  If more columns are needed, add them to the `partition by` clause.

Answer (score 0):

If the checkout date you need is the second (max) date grouped by reason and you want to single out this date then try:

```
select 
  studentID,
  reason,
  max(transactionDate) as checkoutDate
from student
group by
  reason
```